# Disown, nohup or & on Mac OS zsh… not working as hoped

Tags: macos, sleep, zsh, background-process

Hi. I'm new to the shell and am working on my first kludged together script. I've read all over the intertube and SO and there are many, MANY places where `disown`, `nohup`, `&` and `return` are explained but something isn't working for me.

I want a simpler timer. The script asks for user input for the hours, mins., etc., then:

```
echo "No problem, see you then…"
sleep $[a*3600+b*60+c]
```

At this point (either on the first or second lines, not sure) I want the script OR the specific command in the script to become a background process. Maybe a daemon? So that the timer will still go off on schedule even if

that terminal window is shut

the terminal app is quit completely

the computer is put to sleep (I realize I probably need some different code still to wake the mac itself)

Also after the "No problem" line I want a `return` command so that the existing shell window is still useful in the meantime.

The terminal-notifier command (the timer wakeup) is getting called immediately under certain usage of the above (I can't remember which right now), then a second notification at the right time. Using the `return` command anywhere basically seems to quit the script.

One thing I'm not clear on is whether/how `disown`, `nohup`, etc. are applicable to a command process vs. a script process, i.e., will any of them work properly on only a command inside a script (and if not, how to initialize a script as a background process that still asks for input).

Maybe I should use some alternative to `sleep`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't necessary to use a separate script or have the script run itself in order to get part of it to run in the background.

A much simpler way is to place the portions that you want to be backgrounded (the sleep and following command) inside of parentheses, and put an ampersand after them.

So the end of the script would look like:

```
(
  sleep $time
  # Do whatever
)&
```

This will cause that portion of the code to be run inside a subshell which is placed into the background, since there's no code after that the first shell will immediately exit returning control to your interactive shell.

Comment: This is TERRIFIC, thank you! It works perfectly. Now I'm going to look into how to hide the echoed status update issued on completion of the backgrounded process.

Answer (score 0):

When your script is run, it is actually run by starting a new shell to execute it. In order for you to get your script into the background, you would need to send that shell into the background, which you can't do because you would need to communicate with its parent shell.

What you can do is have your script call itself with a special argument to indicate that it should do the work:

```
#! /bin/zsh
if [ "$1" != '--run' ] ; then
    echo sending to background
    $0 --run $@ &
    exit
fi
sleep 1
echo backgrounded $@
```

This script first checks to see if its first argument is `--run`. If it is not, then it calls itself (`$0`) with that argument and all other arguments it received (`$@`) in the background, and exits. You can use a similar method, performing the test when you want to enter the background, and possibly sending the data you will need instead of every argument. For example, to send just the number of seconds:

```
$0 --run $[a*3600+b*60+c] &
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand the general idea but don't know how to incorporate it all yet! I'm glad to know I'm not crazy in that those other commands aren't appropriate/useful here.

Comment: You might find it easier to start by writing two scripts. One gets run in the foreground and collects information, then starts the other in the background. Once you have that working, you can move the code from the second into the first and add the special flag to determine which code to run, then the first just needs to start itself in the background.

Comment: ~7 hours later and I'm still having problems with this so I might need to move onto something less advanced. I don't know if I'm integrating things right, so I made a function with just your script, and it basically works fine unless when it's finished I run it again; then my terminal window closes.I fi stick it into my code the way it seems like I should then terminal tells me I already have jobs running, therefore the --run conditional isn't kicking in (I guess). The notification never happens and the job number is listed as suspended. Hopefully it's ok if I post the script?